# App crashes during API webservice call in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to develop an application in windows phone 8.1 (not universal or silverlight).while I'm doing my API webservice call the app crashes without showing any exception. Can anybody help me to find any solution for this?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();  

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.TryParseAdd("application‌​/json"); 
string response = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("mylink")); 
Maptemp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<MapDet>>(‌​response.ToString())‌​;
```

Comment: Post some code and perhaps a stack trace where it is crashing.

Comment: HttpClient client = new HttpClient();            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.TryParseAdd("application/json");
string response = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("mylink"));
Maptemp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<MapDet>>(response.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

I wish you were more descriptive with your question, but this is what i think.

**Possible causes of error**

1. HttpRequest Error
2. Object reference null error
3. Json Error.

To know exactly where the problem is coming from, either from the web service or from your application, introduce a try catch block sorrounding the code for calling the web service and put a break point at the first curly brace after Catch(Exception). This will help you check the exact contents of the error message.

While making the HttpRequest to the webservice, convert the response to a HttpRensponseMessage so that you can see the response from the server.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.GetAsync("web-service_url");
```

Now inspect the contents of the msg object and tell me what you get.

Comment: request works for first few times(3 or 4 times), after that the app is getting crash without any exception.The scenario is that i have created an app look likes whatsapp. In the main page instead of fragments (android) i used 3 usercontrols  in a single page.in each usercontrols there are three different webservice call.is this the problem for the app crash